# Java File path to Executable has spaces

Tags: java, file, path, space

I have a Java program that asks the user to enter in the path to a file that needs to be executed.

the path can be something like this for example: `C:/ProgramFiles/Citrix/ICA Client/pnagent.exe` I create a `File` Object with this path, and check to make sure it exists, and check to make sure it's a File, and check to make sure it's executable. as far as `File` is concerned, it's a completely valid Object that exists.

*note: the* `File` *object is called "script"*

**BUT** When I run the script, I receive errors on the spaces.

```
Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pp = rt.exec(script.getAbsolutePath());
```

I am 100% the first line works correctly. The error I receive is the image below: (I have it displayed in a JOptionPane.)

[image: Error Image]

What is the best way to remove my errors? Thanks in advanced!

---

Attempted Solution #1:
`Process pp = rt.exec("\""+script.getAbsolutePath()+"\"");`

When I use `C:\Tools\IT Support\bookmark.htm` I get
[image]

Comment: Best way to find/remove errors is to use the debugger.

Comment: @Blaine I tried, I wasn't able to figure it out. Hence why I am posting on here.

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: You'll find solutions in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686592/runtime-exec-on-argument-containing-multiple-spaces

Comment: It would seem to me that that last update you posted shows that `script.getAbsolutePath()` isn't returning a full path. Might check that.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

By far the most reliable way is to use [Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])).

If you use [Runtime.exec(String command)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)), Java only splits the command on whitespace.

> the command string is broken into tokens using a StringTokenizer created by the call new StringTokenizer(command) with no further modification of the character categories. The tokens produced by the tokenizer are then placed in the new string array cmdarray, in the same order.

See also [g++: File not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893148/g-file-not-found)

Or use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ln", "-s", "dir1/dir2", "my dir/dir2");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue, I updated my original post with the results.

Comment: @Kryptos did you try the `ProcessBuilder` approach? Because I don't see the results in your question. If no, please try that

Comment: @c.s. I tried that just now.. I get nothing.. the JFrame freezes, no errors, or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] commands = {"cmd", "/c", "start", "\"DummyTitle\"",script.getAbsolutePath()};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

It is a Windows only solution.

[java.awt.Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) is maybe a better solution in your situation since you need the "file-association" mechanism.

```
public static void open(File document) throws IOException {
    Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
    dt.open(document);
}
```